# Perspective Projection given only field of view

Tags: algorithm, opengl, graphics, 3d, raytracing

I am working on a Perspective camera.  The constructor must be:

```
PerspectiveCamera::PerspectiveCamera(Vec3f &center, Vec3f &direction, Vec3f &up, float angle)
```

This is construction different from most others, as it lacks near and far clipping planes.  I know what to with center, direction, and up -- the standard look at algorithm.

[image: r]

[image: foo+bar]

[image: z]

We can construct the view matrix and translate matrix accordingly:

[image: V]

[image]

Thus, the viewing transformation is:

[image: M]

For an orthographic camera (which is working correctly for me), the inverse transformation is used to go from screen space to world space.  The camera coordinates go from (-1,-1,0) --> (1,1,0) in screen space.

[image: p]

For perspective transformation, only the field of view is given.  The [Wikipedia 3D projection article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) gives  a perspective projection matrix using the field of view angle and assuming camera coordinates go from (-1,-1) --> (1,1):

[image: p]

[image: p]

In my code, (ex,ey,ez) are the camera coordinates that go from (-1,-1, ez) --> (1,1, ez).  Note that the 1 in (3,3) spot of K isn't in the Wikipedia article -- I put it in  to make the matrix invertible.  So that may be a problem.

But anyways, for perspective projection, I used this transformation:

[image: p]

K inverse is multiplied with p to make the canonical view volume to a view frustum, and the result of that is multiplied with M inverse to move into world coordinates.

I get the wrong results.  The correct output is:

[image: Correct result]

My output looks like this:

[image: My result]

Am I using the right algorithm for perspective projection given my constraint (no near and far plane inputs)???

Comment: Is that a typo in your description that the near and far clip planes are equal to one another (ez)? Using the traditional equation for a perspective projection matrix, **m22** and **m23** (where indices begin at **0**) would be infinite if you did that.

Comment: I assume you mean when I said "(-1,-1, ez) --> (1,1, ez)".  No, I don't think means the near and far clip planes.  According to wikipedia,  exyz the viewer's position relative to the display surface.

Comment: The way I thought about is ez is z distance from xy axis assuming you have field of view of alpha and xy coordinates that go from (-1,-1) --> (1,1).  But that is just my guess.

Comment: Oh... there is another problem with your matrix though. For perspective, **m33** (again, where indices begin at 0) is generally **0**. Perspective division would be useless if it were **1**. The 4th row should be `0,0,-1,0` so that the clip-space W coordinate is `-eye_z`

Comment: Yes that would cause problems.  I added the 1 in m33 so the matrix would be invertible.  If the 4th column is  0,0,0,0 then the matrix is singular.  My way is definitely hackish based on different sources -- is there a canonical way to make screen space coordinates into world coordinates given a FOV?

Comment: No, but you can construct a projection matrix from that fov, multiply it by the view matrix and then use its inverse. You will have to divide you screen-space coordinates by their W coordinate before multiplying them by the inverse matrix I mentioned earlier.

Comment: The 4th column is not all zeros in a proper perspective projection matrix, the term in the 3rd row is related to the distance between the near and far clip planes.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody else runs into this issue, the method presented in the question is not proper way to create a viewing frustum.  The perspective matrix (K) is for projecting the far plane onto the near plane, and we don't have those planes in this case

To create a frustum, do the inverse transformation on (x,y,ez) [as opposed to (x,y,0) for orthographic projection).  Find a new direction by subtracting the transformed point from the center of projection.  Shoot the ray.